# Do I need "Install OS X Mavericks" after I've upgraded?

Tags: macos, applications

I have "Install OS X Mavericks" in my Applications folder even though I installed it a while ago. Does the system require this for utilities or something, or is there any reason to keep it around?

Answer (score 3):

No. **If *you* have no use for it, delete it.** The OS doesn't need it any more and if you want to reinstall OS X you can use the Recovery HD, so there's generally no need to keep it.

The post-install script will even delete it for you if its found in the default location as far as I know, but if you still have it there's no problem deleting it yourself.

Comment: only keep it to make a bootable UBS stick as emergency (if nothing else works), after that you can delete it to gain 5 Gig of disk space.